# How does this site generate revenue?

Tags: support, site-policy

I don't see any ads or similar revenue generating materials anywhere in the page. So I am wondering, where does the money come in for maintaining this page? I saw sections about hiring employees, but who pays for them and why? Obviously there should be some kind of ROI.

Answer (score 4):

The Workplace SE is a Stack Exchange Q&A *Beta* site, and sites that are still in the beta phase are in a probationary period where Stack Exchange determines if the Q&A site will be a viable Q&A site that will last indefinitely.

Some beta sites eventually die out and must be closed while others remain in beta until it's clear that there is enough interest and community involvement to where losing a few key members won't significantly impact the site's future success.

Stack Overflow could lose its entire first page of top users, and Stack Overflow would still only have a few scratch marks that are easily buffed out.

So, to answer your question, this site doesn't generate any revenue at the moment, and it's funded through the advertising that exists on the [Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites) that have launched completely, such as Stack Overflow.  Once the Workplace SE graduates, it will contain advertisements and generate revenue.

**UPDATE:**

As others have pointed out, there are ads for Stack Overflow Careers, which is a revenue generator. Additionally, I occasionally see ads for other Stack Exchange Q&A sites, which are yet another way to make Stack Exchange more "sticky" by getting people hooked on topics that interest them.

Comment: thanks for the response

Comment: @decentguy - Here's some more background on [the Beta site SE 2.0 program](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/area-51-first-public-beta/).  Or, [this is probably a better article](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/when-will-my-site-graduate/).

Comment: I'll point out that we're about as official as a "beta" SE site can be, considering how we've been in beta for 383-ish days, haha.

Comment: There is also the SE Careers links that show up sometimes

Comment: Careers earns them a lot, probably the majority, of their money as well